# How to detect a text overflow when using DrawText from SharpDX.Direct2D1?

Tags: c#, direct2d, sharpdx

I'm drawing text to a `RenderForm` in `SharpDX` using:

```
        string s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < log.Count; i++)
            s += log[i] + "\n";
        renderView.DrawText(s, textFormat, logBoundsRect, brush, DrawTextOptions.Clip);
```

However eventually the log list becomes long enough for the text to overflow. How do I detect this overflow so that I can adjust how much of my log list is drawn accordingly?

Comment: You can't with DrawText, you must create a TextLayout (draw it with DrawTextLayout). TextLayout has a GetMetrics method that will tell you the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it thanks to @Simon Mourier's comment.

```
            string s = "";
            TextLayout tl;
            while (true) {
                s = "";
                for (int i = logPosition; i < log.Count; i++) {
                    s += log[i];
                    if (i + 1 < log.Count)
                        s += "\n";
                }
                tl = new TextLayout(factory, s, textformat, logBoundsRect.Width, logBoundsRect.Height);
                if (!(tl.Metrics.Height > logBoundsRect.Height))
                    break;
                logPosition++;
                tl.Dispose();
            };
            renderView.DrawTextLayout(logBoundsRect.TopLeft, tl, brush);
            tl.Dispose();
```

`logPosition` is a global `int` that keeps track of where in the list to start reading from.